# JavaFX window KeyEvent

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to add a KeyEvent eventhandler to my JavaFX window but I get errors when trying to add it to the primarystage or the primaryscene.

How would I go about adding the eventhandler to the window?

My Handler

```
EventHandler<KeyEvent> handler = event -> {
    switch (event.getCode()) {
        case UP:
            System.out.println("up");
            break;
        case DOWN:
            System.out.println("down");
            break;
        case LEFT:
            System.out.println("left");
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            System.out.println("right");
            break;
    }
};
```

Adding it to the scene

```
 mainScene.addEventHandler(EventType.ROOT, handler);
```

Error:

> Error:(75, 18) java: method addEventHandler in class
>   javafx.scene.Scene cannot be applied to given types;   required:
>   javafx.event.EventType,javafx.event.EventHandler
>   found:
>   javafx.event.EventType,javafx.event.EventHandler
>   reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
>       equality constraints: javafx.event.Event
>       upper bounds: javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent,javafx.event.Event

Comment: [Edit] your question to show how you are trying to add this handler to the scene. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler is an `EventHandler<KeyEvent>`: that is, it is a handler that handles key events. So you have to register it to handle events whose type is some type of `KeyEvent`. ([`EventType.ROOT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventType.html#ROOT) is an `EventType<Event>`, not an `EventType<KeyEvent>`.)

If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html), you will see that the possible event types are

- `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED`
- `KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED`
- `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED`
- `KeyEvent.ANY`

Note, again from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCode--), that `getCode()` will always return `KeyCode.UNDEFINED` for `KEY_TYPED` events, so you presumably want either `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED` or `KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED`, i.e.

```
mainScene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, handler);
```

or

```
mainScene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, handler);
```

Note that there are also the convenience methods [`Scene.setOnKeyPressed(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#setOnKeyPressed-javafx.event.EventHandler-), etc, though you can only register a single handler with these.